# How to UNDO last edit 'References' files from the project in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm creating an application on C#. By mistake, I have added some references to my project's **References** folder. And I don't know which of them have been added recently. Is there any key combination or any section in menu which takes the action back? Just like when we miss type on word document or miss coded on Visual Studio, as we can use **`ctrl + Z`** key combination to undo it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There is no key combination or undo facility for this.

Your best option is to use a source control system, then you can undo your check out (or do a get-latest) on the project file that you added the references to.

Alternatively, plugins like ReSharper can offer options like `Remove unused references` which can help.

Comment: I see that. Thanks for answer. Btw it is going to be another question but can I use source control system just for my local pc?

Comment: @curiousBoy You sure can, although it is more common to keep it on a different machine for various reasons. To make things easy, check out the online versions of Git and TFS, there are ways of using either for free.

Comment: slugster, I do appreciate for suggestion. Cheers